# push to Heroku failed / rake aborting! :: precompiling assets failed to compile Ruby app

Tags: ruby, heroku, deployment

I've upgraded the tool belt and setup an app in my Heroku account named tycoon but I'm getting an error trying to push to Heroku using git push Heroku master.

There were conflicts pushing to an existing app I deployed earlier so I deleted that app and created a new app called tycoon, but when I do a push i get the error I pasted down below.

It's difficult to make out what it was that tripped it up because it appears to be throwing the error (rake aborted!) in the middle or just after loading the logo image. Then after that, the first file it lists in the error reporting is a JS file (assets/javascript/application), but every line in that file is commented out so it's basically blank and I can't see how that could be causing this deployment error.

```
  ! Precompiling assets failed.
  ! Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
  To git@heroku.com:tycoon.git
  ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
  error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:tycoon.git'

cecs470@cecs470-VirtualBox:~/Tycoon3.git$ git push heroku master
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 1241, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (857/857), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1241/1241), 1.32 MiB | 262 KiB/s, done.
Total 1241 (delta 810), reused 610 (delta 343)
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
New app detected loading default bundler cache
Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Fetching https://github.com/rails/rails.git
Fetching git://github.com/rails/coffee-rails.git
Fetching git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git
Fetching https://github.com/rails/sass-rails.git
Using rake (10.1.0)
Installing i18n (0.6.9)
Using minitest (4.7.5)
Using multi_json (1.8.2)
Using atomic (1.1.14)
Using thread_safe (0.1.3)
Using tzinfo (0.3.38)
Using activesupport (4.0.2) from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 4-0-stable)
Using builder (3.1.4)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using rack (1.5.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.2)
Using actionpack (4.0.2) from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 4-0-stable)
Installing mime-types (1.25.1)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.15)
Using mail (2.5.4)
Using actionmailer (4.0.2) from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 4-0-stable)
Using activemodel (4.0.2) from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 4-0-stable)
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
Using arel (4.0.1)
Using activerecord (4.0.2) from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 4-0-stable)
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2)
Using sass (3.2.12)
Installing bootstrap-sass (3.0.2.0)
Installing climate_control (0.0.3)
Installing cocaine (0.5.3)
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
Using execjs (2.0.2)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using thor (0.18.1)
Using railties (4.0.2) from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 4-0-stable)
Using coffee-rails (4.0.1) from git://github.com/rails/coffee-rails.git (at master)
Installing faker (1.2.0)
Installing hash-deep-merge (0.1.1)
Using hike (1.2.3)
Installing jbuilder (1.0.2)
Using jquery-rails (3.0.4)
Using json (1.8.1)
Using bundler (1.3.2)
Installing lazy_high_charts (1.5.0)
Installing mortgage_calc (0.1.8)
Using paperclip (3.5.2) from git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git (at master)
Installing pg (0.15.1)
Using tilt (1.4.1)
Installing sprockets (2.10.1)
Using sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
Using rails (4.0.2) from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at 4-0-stable)
Using rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.1)
Using rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
Using rails_12factor (0.0.2)
Using rdoc (3.12.2)
Using sass-rails (4.0.1) from https://github.com/rails/sass-rails.git (at master)
Using sdoc (0.3.20)
Installing turbolinks (1.1.1)
Installing uglifier (2.1.1)
Installing will_paginate (3.0.5)
Installing will_paginate-bootstrap (1.0.0)
Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
Bundle completed (83.21s)
Cleaning up the bundler cache.
Removing coffee-rails (4.0.1)
Removing activeresource (3.2.14)
Removing actionpack (4.0.1)
Removing sass (3.2.10)
Removing activesupport (3.2.14)
Removing arel (3.0.2)
Removing builder (3.0.4)
Removing kgio (2.8.1)
Removing activemodel (4.0.1)
Removing jbuilder (1.5.2)
Removing sass-rails (4.0.1)
Removing coffee-rails (3.2.2)
Removing railties (4.0.1)
Removing tzinfo (0.3.37)
Removing puma (2.6.0)
Removing mini_portile (0.5.1)
Removing sprockets (2.2.2)
Removing execjs (2.0.1)
Removing sprockets (2.10.0)
Removing rails_stdout_logging (0.0.2)
Removing sass-rails (3.2.6)
Removing rack (1.4.5)
Removing jbuilder (1.5.1)
Removing activerecord (4.0.1)
Removing unicorn (4.6.3)
Removing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
Removing journey (1.0.4)
Removing rack-ssl (1.3.3)
Removing activemodel (3.2.14)
Removing actionmailer (4.0.1)
Removing i18n (0.6.5)
Removing rack-cache (1.2)
Removing activerecord (3.2.14)
Removing activesupport (4.0.1)
Removing nokogiri (1.6.0)
Removing uglifier (2.3.1)
Removing pg (0.17.0)
Removing json (1.8.0)
Removing mime-types (1.25)
Removing raindrops (0.12.0)
Removing actionpack (3.2.14)
Removing multi_json (1.8.0)
Removing uglifier (2.2.1)
Removing actionmailer (3.2.14)
Removing rails (4.0.1)
Removing turbolinks (1.3.1)
Removing rails (3.2.14)
Removing railties (3.2.14)
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
Running: rake assets:precompile
I, [2013-12-12T07:21:34.932976 #1556] INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/public/assets/american_dream_home-37874daacff06fbb26eb8b84ee1f84a1.jpg
I, [2013-12-12T07:21:34.935188 #1556] INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/public/assets/cabin_style_dream_home-9987333105c1424b8fc9aaf7c1efbf07.jpg
I, [2013-12-12T07:21:34.937405 #1556] INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/public/assets/contemporary_dream_home-1e8e61d0591ec26a104029ab0e92906c.jpg
I, [2013-12-12T07:21:34.939250 #1556] INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/public/assets/csulb_logo-b94fb88ec35ebf0db98c07a4fa00e6ed.jpg
I, [2013-12-12T07:21:34.941295 #1556] INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/public/assets/tycoon_corporate_building-c4adcb12e189ad0215568925af112601.png
I, [2013-12-12T07:21:34.943313 #1556] INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/public/assets/tycoon_header_logo-66f7c71223c8377c2f56dd1261011a65.jpg
I, [2013-12-12T07:21:34.945011 #1556] INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/public/assets/tycoon_logo_black-29edd8d4b49980a739dfdb52c2464007.png
I, [2013-12-12T07:21:34.946625 #1556] INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/public/assets/tycoon_logo_black_2-d92244c141090ac417f460b7a9d2fbe2.png
rake aborted!
Unexpected token: name (side) (line: 10600, col: 22, pos: 329089)
Error
at new JS_Parse_Error (/tmp/execjs20131212-1556-dj66x9.js:2316:10736)
at js_error (/tmp/execjs20131212-1556-dj66x9.js:2316:10955)
at croak (/tmp/execjs20131212-1556-dj66x9.js:2316:18665)
at token_error (/tmp/execjs20131212-1556-dj66x9.js:2316:18802)
at unexpected (/tmp/execjs20131212-1556-dj66x9.js:2316:18890)
at semicolon (/tmp/execjs20131212-1556-dj66x9.js:2316:19363)
at simple_statement (/tmp/execjs20131212-1556-dj66x9.js:2316:21849)
at /tmp/execjs20131212-1556-dj66x9.js:2316:20090
at /tmp/execjs20131212-1556-dj66x9.js:2316:19536
at /tmp/execjs20131212-1556-dj66x9.js:2316:31209
(in /tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)/tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:68:in `extract_result'
/tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:28:in `block in exec'
/tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:41:in `compile_to_tempfile'
/tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:27:in `exec'
/tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/uglifier-2.1.1/lib/uglifier.rb:176:in `really_compile'
/tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/uglifier-2.1.1/lib/uglifier.rb:100:in `compile'
/tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:25:in `evaluate'
/tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
/tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
/tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
/tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
/tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:25:in `initialize'
/tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
/tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
/tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
/tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
/tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
/tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
/tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
/tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'
/tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in `benchmark'
/tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
/tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in `block in compile'
/tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
/tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `compile'
/tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:60:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
/tmp/build_1529804d-f800-4525-b124-7f75c73ebdf1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in define'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
!
! Precompiling assets failed.
!
! Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
To git@heroku.com:tycoon.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:tycoon.git'
cecs470@cecs470-VirtualBox:~/Tycoon3.git$
```

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you may try asking in #heroku on IRC: https://webchat.freenode.net. The people there are usually very helpful.

Comment: try in local machine `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` you can track the error.